# Using RSpec to check if something is an instance of another object

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, instance

I need a way to check if an object is an instance of another object using RSpec. For example:

```
describe "new shirt" do
  it "should be an instance of a Shirt object"
    # How can i check if it is an instance of a shirt object
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that an object is never an "instance of another object." An object is an instance of a *class*, not another object.

Comment: @JacobLockard Classes are objects in Ruby. The Ruby documentation states: "Classes in Ruby are first-class objects—each is an instance of class Class." and "When a new class is created, an object of type Class is initialized and assigned to a global constant." https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Class.html

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The preferred syntax is:

```
expect(@object).to be_a Shirt
```

The older syntax is:

```
@object.should be_an_instance_of Shirt
```

Note that there is a very subtle difference between the two. If Shirt were to inherit from Garment then **both of these expectations will pass**:

```
expect(@object).to be_a Shirt
expect(@object).to be_a Garment
```

If you do and @object is a Shirt, then the **second expectation will fail**:

```
@object.should be_an_instance_of Shirt
@object.should be_an_instance_of Garment
```

Answer (score 8):

You mean you want to check if an object is an instance of a *class*? If so, that's easy, just use `class`:

```
@object.class.should == Shirt
```